# How to differentiate M:N relationships without intersect tables from M:N relationships with intersect tables

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

My goal is to get invoices related to given contact, if I acquire data from the table named "contactinvoices" (intersect table), then I see that this table is empty. I have solved that Problem by requesting records directly from invoice table with "contactid" (contacts) = "costumerid" (invoices). As I see now that this approach is good for contact and account tables and for invoices and quotes. How to differentiate M:N relationships without intersect tables from M:N relationships with intersect tables

Comment: You're asking three questions, and none of them are very specific.  Are you asking how to perform joins in SQL, or with Linq, or with Query Expressions, or Fetch Xml?

Comment: Ok, you are right, i have rewritten this question, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270805/how-to-differentiate-mn-relationships-without-intersect-tables-from-mn-relatio

Comment: Don't file a new question. Edit this one.

Comment: ok, edited and the other one - deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a Many to Many relationship without an intersection table.  Lets review some terms:

### M:1

Lets take Customers and Orders for example.  A Customer can have multiple orders, but an order can have only one customer (even though multiple orders can have the same customer).  This is achieved by an Order having a CustomerId field.

### M:N

Let's take Authors and Books for example.  An Author can write multiple books, and a Book can be written by one or more Authors.  The Book having an AuthorId will not achieve this relationship, and this is where the intersect table is required.  It contains an AuthorId, and a BookId.  If two Authors work on the same Book, the intersect table will have two records with the same BookId, and differing AuthorIds, thus allowing for the M:N relationship.

### M:1 & M:N?

You can also have both if there are slightly different uses of the relationship.  Let's say for example that you have Contacts and Orders, and the Customer is a Contact, and the Order also has one or more Sales Reps that handle the order.  Now the Contact table and Order table are related twice.  The Order table could have a CustomerId attribute that is actually a foreign key to the Contact Table.  But then there could also be an intersect table of Orders and Sales Reps, in which the Sales Reps are again foreign keys to the Contact table.

---

So in answer to your question, how do you differentiate?  If it has an intersect table, it is a M:N relationship, if it doesn't, it isn't.

Comment: But Contacts and Invoices have an intersect table, and this table is always empty.

Comment: @Igor I've never dealt with Invoices in CRM.  I'm guessing it is to represent some other relationship between Inovices and Contacts, rather than the purchaser (maybe suppliers?).

Comment: Oh my god, you are right! It was other relationship! many thanks!